# What is the meaning of DATA SEGMENT USE16 PARA PUBLIC 'DATA' when defining a data segment?

Tags: assembly

I use 80x86 Assembly language.

```
DATA SEGMENT USE16 PARA PUBLIC 'DATA'
DAT DW 0AH
TMP DB 'WWWWW$' ;中间过程用
TGT DB 'WWWWW$' ;16位二进制数转换后至多为5位加上结束符‘$’
DATA ENDS
```

Comment: PARA means it's paragraph-aligned (16-byte) so the seg:off address can be `xxxx:0000`

Comment: And what does "public data' mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The `SEGMENT` directive can take the two forms](http://bitsavers.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/pdf/borland/turbo_assembler/Turbo_Assembler_Version_5_Users_Guide.pdf):

```
name SEGMENT [attributes]

SEGMENT name [attributes]
```

The first one is used in this case.

---

`DATA`
This is the name of the segment

`SEGMENT`
This is the first form of segment directive.

`USE16`
When used in a code segment declaration, this defines the default operand size.
When used in a data segment it limits the maximum size of the segment.

`PARA`
Align on paragraphs (16-byte).

`PUBLIC`
This segment will be concatenated with other segments of the same name outside of the module to form a single contiguous segment.

`'DATA'`
This is the segment class. It is used by the linker to order and group (concat) the segments at linking time. Each segment with the same class is grouped together but other grouping is also possible (e.g. data and uninitialised data).

Comment: What does "Align on paragraphs (16-byte)." mean?

Comment: @昱文米 It means the starting address of the segment is a multiple of 16. When segment are merged, zero bytes are added in between to make the latter segment start at a multiple of 16. Starting at a multiple of 16 allows the programmer to access the start of the segment with an address of the form: `xxxx:0000` (as Peter pointed out). This allows to use a single segment register to address the whole data, even it reaches 64KiB in length.